# When i run the Sonar-Scanner got Execution Failure in terminal or commandline

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I want to generate reports through command line or from terminal NOT FROM BROWSER

NOTE:- I want to verify through typescript the code sonar-scanner

I have install sonarqube-8.5.1.38104 and sonar-scanner-4.5.0.2216-linux and react-app-sonarqube.

In react-app-sonarqube i have all files are there screenshot is
[image]

[image]

And here is my below screenshot which i have run from terminal
[image]

and
[image: image image1256×587 119 KB]

I’m new to sonar and i dont know to generate reports through terminal or command line

Please help me how can i solve and any link or commands

Comment: What is the content of the `test-report.xml` file?

Comment: nothing is empty file

Answer (score 0):

The failure is caused by problem with parsing the `test-report.xml` file. As you wrote in the comment this file is empty. Empty file is not a valid XML file.

If this file is:

- generated by a tool - you have to check this tool configuration (it is broken)
- added manually by you - you have to delete it